# export multiple files in nrwl nx library projects into apps

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

New at using `nx` for front end development. I have the following project / lib structure

```
apps
 - single-spa
 - standalone

lib
 - business
   - index.tsx
```

The app `single-spa` references `business`. There are multiple sub folders in `business` at the moment. I have to manually add an entry into `index.tsx` for each of the component that single-spa directly OR indirectly uses

sample entry in index.txs

```
export * from pages/page01.js
export * from pages/page02.js
```

Is there an easier way to export components from lib/business ?

Comment: short answer: no. Long answer: you could write a script that automaticly scans your folder scruture and fills your index.tsx file.